# Function returning struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Where can we write code like

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    int baz;
} foo()
{

}
```

C89/C90? C99? C11? Or maybe it's K&R only?

And what about this

```
void foo(bar, baz)
int bar;
int baz;
{
}
```

Comment: Not sure, what you are trying to achieve in first example but Second is K&R and format of function definition, it is not approved by C standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's standard since C89. In K&R C, it was not possible to return structs, only pointers to structs.

Comment: Thanks! And i can't use this in any C++ standard, yes?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: You can certainly return structs in C++, too, but you can't define them in the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and useful, certainly since C89, to return a `struct`.

Your second example `foo` is old K&R C and is deprecated in newer standards.

Notice that on Linux x86-64 the [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) defines [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) which returns a two membered structure directly thru registers. Other structures are returned thru memory, so may be a little slower to return than a single pointer.

For instance, you could define a point to be a `struct` of two numbers (e.g. `int` or `double`) called `x` and `y` and return such a `struct` from some `getPosition` routine. On Linux/x86-64, the two numbers would be returned in two registers (without bothering building some `struct` in memory, when optimization is enabled and possible), e.g.:

```
 struct point_st { int x, y; };

 struct point_st getPosition(void);

 struct point_st getPosition () {
   struct point_st res = {-1,-1};
   res.x = input_x();
   res.y = input_y();
   return res;
 };
```

You generally want to declare the returned `struct` before the function's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

In C89/C90, it is possible to have a function that returns a struct.

I didn't find any explicit definition in the standard, but a footnote in section 3.3.2.3 "Structure and Union Members" says:

> EXAMPLE 1: If **f** is a function returning a structure or union, and **x** is a member of that structure or union, **f().x** is a valid postfix expression but is not an lvalue.

Section 3.6.6.4 "The return Statement" doesn't lose a word about structures and unions as return types though.

Section 3.5.4.3 "Function declarators (including prototypes)" says:

> A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type.

It does not mention any restriction on structure or union types, and since this would be the place where such a restriction would belong, they are allowed.

C99 has the same wording, it just renumbered the sections.